# A close button that finishes all activities

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

I have 5 activities in my android app,on last activity  i want a close button that exits the app by finishing every activity one by one?

Comment: You should show some code of what you've tried already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the next steps:

In the activity where you want to exit do the this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, RootActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);//this will clear all the stack
intent.putExtra("extra_exit", true);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

and in RootActivity.class's onCreate and onNewIntent:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
    ...
    if(!checkExtraToExit(intent)){
        //do activity initialization
        ...
    }
    ...
}

public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    if(!checkExtraToExit(intent)){
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
    }
} 

public boolean checkExtraToExit(Intent intent){
    if( intent.getBooleanExtra("extra_exit", false)){
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your onclick listener. it will close the application.

```
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: this will close the app, but i want to close all the activities one by one.

Comment: @SamiUlHaq: then you must use a service.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought calling `startActivityForResult` and in `onActivityResult` check the right code and result and call `finish`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);//this will clear all the stack
intent.putExtra("sometext", true);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

then in YourActivity in onCreate() write below lines

```
if( getIntent().getBooleanExtra("sometext", false)){
    finish();
    return; // it will take you out
}
```